# Why would including <regex> cause sqrt( negative number ) to throw domain exceptions

Tags: c++, regex, sqrt

I have a program that regularly takes the std::sqrt() of negative numbers and checks for NaN as required.

Using gcc 6.3.0 (on an embedded platform), if I

```
#include <regex>
```

in the same library, instead of returning NaN it will throw an exception.

The same code runs correctly when built using GCC 8.1 (in Windows) and Clang (in Mac)

I tried explicitly setting

```
#define math_errhandling MATH_ERRNO
```

before calling all my other headers and it doesn't seem to have an effect.

Update:

I tracked this down to __errno() being the actual problem here. I found that in a 3rd party library there was a declaration:

```
int __errno = 0;
```

Which will clearly cause a seg fault if called as a function.

It’s still not clear why including regex caused it to link to this library, but removing this fixes the problem.

Comment: Why do you expect your #define to have any effect?

Comment: Re: NaN, Yes that was a typo, I do check NaN.

I tried the #define, because it seemed like the math error handling was for some reason changing to MATH_ERREXCEPT based on:
```
#define MATH_ERRNO        1 (since C++11)
#define MATH_ERREXCEPT    2 (since C++11)
#define math_errhandling  /*implementation defined*/
```

Comment: The error behavior is defined here:
https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/math_errhandling

Comment: It sounds like something enabled traps for floating point exceptions. On linux see `feenableexcept` or `_controlfp` for Windows. It seems unlikely that `<regex>` would do that. Maybe you have UB somewhere in your code, and it is corrupting the state of floating point exception trapping somehow?

Comment: @JoshP this macro is defined *by the library* for your program to know what the library supports. The library does not use it.

Comment: Can you post a [mcve]?

Comment: can't reproduce it.. BUT, from what I can tell it seems like a linking issue. At some point regex started working, but now if I use stoi() it will fault. When I tried to reproduce, the debugger will step into sqrt() -> std::sqrt() and no fault. In the fault code, I can't step into sqrt() and the debugger says there is no sqrt() in std namespace. Seems like some mixture of c++/c headers confusion might be causing it to link to different libraries.

Note: Linking is handled automagically by the dev environment.

Comment: @JoshP The problem of including regex and getting different floating point behavior sounds to me a bit as if it automatically changes the floating point exceptions when. It could also link or load an additional library which was compiled with `-ffast-math`. See [here](https://simonbyrne.github.io/notes/fastmath/), quote: _GCC with -funsafe-math-optimizations enables FTZ (and its close relation, denormals-are-zero, or DAZ), even when building shared libraries. That means simply loading a shared library can change the results in completely unrelated code, which is a fun debugging experience._